# How to properly use CUDA pipeline in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Hello I am developing CUDA C++ application. I would like to use CUDA interactive debugger in visual studio but cmake projects seem to be not supported (am I wrong?).

So I am trying to switch from cmake to visual studio project. Hovewer I run into strange problem.

Without any importanta changes in code  I have error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Multiple definition of '_ZN4cuda3__48pipelineILNS_3std3__48__detail12thread_scopeE2EE25__barrier_try_wait_parityERNS0_7barrierILS5_2ENS3_18__empty_completionEEEb' in 'x64/Debug/MainPassFunctions.cu.obj', first defined in 'x64/Debug/BiggerMainFunctions.cu.obj' CUDADebugB  C:\Users\1\source\repos\CUDADebugB\CUDALINK 1
```

when I try to use function where argument is defined as :

```
cuda::pipeline< cuda::thread_scope_block>& pipeline
```

Begining of my cu file

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <cuda/pipeline>
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
#include <cuda_pipeline.h>

using namespace cooperative_groups;
```

in cmake project all worked well with cmake as below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(hello LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
enable_language(CUDA)


find_package(hdf5 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -lineinfo  -rdc=true -lcudadevrt")
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 80)
add_executable(hello hello.cu  )
include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(hello PRIVATE hdf5::hdf5-shared hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared hdf5::hdf5_cpp-shared hdf5::hdf5_hl_cpp-shared)
target_link_libraries(hello PRIVATE GTest::gmock GTest::gtest GTest::gmock_main GTest::gtest_main)
```

now my vs studio project settings

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What i should change to make it work?

Comment: It looks like you have two definitions for the same function, one in the `MainPassFunctions` object file, and the other in the `BiggerMainFunctions` object file.

Comment: You are right Thanks !!! I do not know why it worked on cmake and did not here but it works now thanks !!

Comment: I'm glad I was of any help. In the CMake file you probably aren't linking together those two object files (maybe not even compiling the two them). I don't really know.

Answer (score -3):

Answer by
rturrado solved the problem
"
It looks like you have two definitions for the same function, one in the MainPassFunctions object file, and the other in the BiggerMainFunctions object file."

So I just fused two files into one.

Comment: This is not a proper answer, Jakub. With my comment above, I just interpreted the linker error you were getting. That gave you a hint on what to do next to fix the issue. But we don't know what you did. That's exactly what you should detail in your answer. I'm sure it will help other users having similar problems in the future.